# Hide text ONLY for screen readers

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility, wcag2.0

I simply can't get the answer to this question. The WCAG says it can be done by `aria-hidden` tag, but I've read it's not working at many screen readers.

Can't get how `display:none` can help to hide some text **only** for screen readers(=visible to other devices than SR). This is also not clear how would screen reader act for `display:none` if it not supports css.

Is there any technique or best practice or whatever I can use to hide some text **only** for screen readers?

Comment: why should it be 'unseen' ? ... an img tag with an empty alt attribute does this.

Comment: why? can't you think about a situation like this? Just think for a moment that users with SR use the device so the text would be readable for voice engines. Try to read some symbols, http address etc... got the idea?

Comment: my question was more like, how come you run in this situation ? does `speak:none;` or `voice-volume:silent;` has no effects ? https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-speech/

Comment: [OP also asked this on Webmasters.](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/89082/17633)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aria-hidden` should be used to hide any non-focusable content on a page from screen readers. All major screen readers current versions support this well.

In oder to [satisfy WCAG 2 AA](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#accessibility-supporteddef), a feature only needs to be supported on the common or at least one widely distributed free assistive technology. NVDA and Firefox on Windows, VoiceOver on OS X and iOS and Talkback with Firefox on Android all support this feature.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, the best practice is to use `aria-hidden` attribute. Users with screen readers ignoring ARIA attributes should change their software.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `role="presentation"`, depending of the tag, browser and screen reader it can be a better option (or worse). Take a look at this good tutorial,

[HTML5 Accessibility: aria-hidden and role=”presentation”](http://john.foliot.ca/aria-hidden/)