# Hide a purely decorative element for screen readers?

Tags: html, svg, wai-aria, voiceover, screen-readers

A similar question was asked here [Hide text ONLY for screen readers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963409/hide-text-only-for-screen-readers.The) recommendation was to use `aria-hidden` and this does not seem to work with images and SVG.

I have an SVG which is just a line, so I don’t want screen readers to read it. Right now a screen reader reads "image" when walking over that SVG.

I tried `aria-hidden="true"`, `role="presentation"`, `style="speak:none;"`, `tabindex="-1"` and all together but none worked. I tested with Mac OSX 10.11.5 Voice Over, which would ALWAYS read out the word "image". Is there no way to hide decorative stuff from screen readers? How do you handle it?

```
<h2 class="copy works__title">
  portfolio
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" class="zigzag--small">
    <use role="presentation" xlink:href="assets/svg/sprite.svg#zigzag-small"></use>
  </svg>
</h2>
```

Comment: Tried adding `aria-hidden="true"` to wrapper of SVG?

Comment: Both `role="presentation"` and `aria-hidden="true"` [should suppress announcement](http://www.w3.org/TR/svg-aam-1.0/#mapping), might be a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right so

• It seems to be a **Firefox bug** (46.0.1) with VoiceOver on Mac OSX 10.11.5

I’ve done a lot more tests: it seems that it might be impossible to suppress the reading of some elements in firefox (at least for VoiceOver on Mac) I’ve tried out several things and I was not able to hide images nor svg unless they are part of a stronger context as within an tag. But in normal context any image with all those fancy tags `aria-hidden="true", role="presentation", style="speak:none;", tabindex="-1"` and removing the alt tag or leaving the alt tag blank would have the VoiceOver read out "image" (even for svgs) – where a blind person might feel left out… However it is working in all other browsers… Shame on you FF :(

If anyone knows a solution/hack please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open bug with Firefox that itself collects related bugs and dependencies. It last saw activity on January 20, 2016, while the related bugs aren't that recently updated.

Some of those bugs:

- [Bug 974351 - (aria-hidden) [meta] aria-hidden implementation](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=974351) (the aggregating bug)
- [Bug 948540 - aria-hidden ignored by VoiceOver](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=948540)
- [Bug 1123248 - incorrect accessible name calculation - includes hidden content](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1123248)
- [Bug 974351 - (aria-hidden) [meta] aria-hidden implementation](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=974351)
- [Bug 1147359 - aria-hidden state not honoured with CSS generated content](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1147359)

For this situation you should probably include an accessible name telling users that it is decorative. There is a great article that may be helpful: [Tips for Creating Accessible SVG](https://www.sitepoint.com/tips-accessible-svg/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set an empty text alternative. Then the browser should consider it is a purely decorative image

```
<svg aria-labelledby="svgtitle1">
     <title id="svgtitle1"></title>
     [other svg code]
</svg>
```

Comment: Do not do that. The browser won't consider it anything other than what it is just because you intentionally exclude an accessibility feature. This has the effect of negatively impacting users who would benefit from useful text here, just to address a bug in one browser.

Comment: @aardrian There is no useful text here because it is a **purely decorative element**. You have to provide a text alternative even if empty for decorative elements.

Comment: good point. I am primed from experience to assume all SVG images can and will be re-used as non-decorative items. The example here is pretty clearly only decorative. My apologies.